# Could a "vampire restaurant" be logistically feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, economy, vampires

There's this reasonably common concept in vampire fiction when the vampires are open members of society: oftentimes there are these businesses where vampires pay to drink blood straight from humans' bodies. The reasons for this generally vary between "the blood doesn't keep well and is tastiest/healthiest when fresh" to "it's just more fun that way", but for the purposes of this question the particular reason doesn't matter. What I'm curious about is whether or not the logistics would be realistic if you made a business, whether it be a restaurant or some kind of "Uber Eats" home delivery thing, that makes its money hiring humans to consensually and non-lethally get their blood drunk by paying vampires.

Because on the surface it seems like a pretty daunting undertaking. Humans can only healthily donate a pint of blood approximately once every two months. Assuming a vampire's daily blood needs aren't significantly beneath that, that would mean that for every customer the service can cater to in one night, they would need a rotating staff of *sixty* part-time employees who would *really* be stretching the concept of "part-time" to breaking point, because they'd each only come in for one night of work at the business every two months.

But despite only working for the company as an extra side-thing once every two months for a little extra cash, each of those employees would have to get proper employee training, and they'd probably also need refresher courses given how infrequently they'll be getting practice. That seems like a *lot* of overhead for a very big workforce.

**Could a company realistically make money if it has to maintain an ultra-part-time workforce of 60 people for every one customer they get a night?**

Comment: One option could be to supply each server with a blood transfusion after each customer they served.

Comment: How "fresh" is needed? Can one just pretend to be the Red Cross and set up a donation collecting station that server its product to Vampires rather than Hospitals?

Comment: @Philipp Is that doable? That seems super unhealthy at first blush.

Comment: @JonSG For the purposes of this question, we're talking about the trope of paying to drink straight from humans.

Comment: If it’s operating as a pseudo-legitimate, non-black-market business in daylight world, then its primary competition would be the medical industry’s blood services which already essentially exist using this model. Simple google search returns multiple examples: https://www.cslplasma.com/rewards-for-current-donors?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5KDphf2m8wIVOAaICR1plAJOEAAYASAEEgIOWfD_BwE If Deacon Frost can set up blood raves in meat-packing plants, then creative vampires or their human allies could likely manage someway to work through the business regulatory systems.

Comment: From the perspective of basic (and simplified) economics, what you really want is no more than 10% of your gross revenue to be used for payroll. So the answer to your question is always "yes" so long as the cost of the meal is high enough and the clientele are willing to pay it. As a small business owner, 60 employees (oh, say \$15/hr, 40 hr weeks = \$36k/wk) to one customer (eats once a week, the meal costs \$360k) sounds a hair unreasonable. But rich people do odd things (anything by Nicki Minaj comes to mind).

Comment: NAA but a similar idea was done in the television drama True Blood. A vampire owns such a restsurant in Louisiana and while they dont employ humans for this for legal reasons, they do cater to human patrons as well to give the whole vampire experience. They also turn a blind eye to the humans that sell their bodies for nourishment and entertainment at their establishment.

Comment: I recommend reading ‘The Phlebotomist’ by Chris Panatier. While it’s not about a vampire restaurant per se it does dive pretty deep into the economics and feasibility of regular (and often too regular) blood donations and the social setup that allows/requires them.

Answer (score 6):

The American Red Cross recommend that you should wait 8 weeks between blood donations. This is to prevent developing anemia. You can lose more blood and more often than that, but doing this often for long term will develop severe health effects. Now, if you have a professional "blood bag" you are probably taking action to staying healthy, working out and taking supplements and drugs to keep your blood count high and stave off anemia. in this way, the professional "blood bag" can charge a premium for their blood. There is also an issue with soft tissue damage at the drain site and possibility of infection. Frequent donators would need some kind of medical maintenance to stay in the business, requiring a high price tag.

With this, I cannot imagine a provider could donate more than once every other week, even with maintaining a high quality blood system, but that would be really pushing it and you wouldnt be able to stay in the business for long. But if you are charging $5000 a hit, then it may be worth it to some.

Now, as L.Dutch answered, it all depends on your clientele. If you have some vampires just looking for a quick blood fix, stopping into some "fast blood restaurant" you can pay a bunch of crack heads 10 dollars a pop and charge the vampire $50 for a tasty treat. A more refined customer, looking for some quality blood, maybe hit up their favorite provider, then they would be paying top dollar for a gourmet meal.

Basically, you can look at the prostitution industry on how to charge clients. Anyone can get services for 20 dollars, but if you are looking for quality service, you could be charging $5000 for it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliot_Spitzer_prostitution_scandal for what some people would pay for services.

Comment: Possible tissue damage can be ameliorated with a permanent cannula or similar.

Comment: That would require a dedication to the trade as a blood supplier. It may allow for a more frequent call to duty, but it would still be once every few weeks for a long term professional. Not totally versed on the effects of long term blood letting is, even with dedication to maintaining ones health, but I assume over taxing the circulatory system too long and too often would cause something to give up. maybe the spleen giving out or mineral absorption rates faltering, causing a detrimental change in blood chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the target customers.

In the same way as you can't eat fresh lobsters, wagyu or caviar for 1 \$, I assume that using the services of this restaurant won't be cheap, which incidentally also matches with the common depiction of vampires as belonging to the well off.

At the end the choice is between paying good money for a clean eating, or venturing in the streets for a cheaper and more riskier meal.

If the customer can afford to pay enough, it's totally possible that the paid amount can be enough for a pool of 60 employees dedicated to him/her.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can make money. They just have to do certain things:

- Be "smart" with how they get people on the table.
- Charge the vampires enough to get money.
- Provide an overall experience.

I'd also add

Restaurants by default provide a "extra" service. You are not just paying for the price of the food. You are paying for the quality of food, the atmosphere, the service...etc.

Meaning we already have restaurants catering to certain paying customers that are willing to just throw money away. We also have cheaper alternatives that maybe offer you the chance to get the kids to play away from you in peace for an hour. Or others that that just put good cheap food on your plate and be done with it.

So. It's all about what they provide. High class establishments would be a thing for vampires as they are for humans. The quality of the "product" is meaningless in a since.
If you do the whole experience right, they can suck on grade C blood and be happier than if they sucked on grade A blood from a stranger down the street.

**Smart business**

Why bother trying to go the old fashion way in providing human cattle that is practically drugged all the time while the world is full to the brim with blood regenerating providers?
That's just stupid. Streamline the process.

You have any idea how many teenagers, college kids, working parents...etc would be willing to get paid for blood donation? You have any idea how easy it would be to handle the whole thing with geolocation services, cellphones, waiting lists...etc?

Basically create a system designed to save money and time and just make it easier.

I will put that in points since I think it might get out of hand

- First create a library of providers. Don't want a greedy person donating twice in a week, dying. Then you getting hit with a law suit.
- Simple 1 page instructions on how they should act when the vampire sucks their blood. Optional explaining to first timers. Regular providers already know what is going on. Meaning less time
- Also you can use mild drugs or alcohol to help if they are nervous.
- Build a nice waiting area. Console, tv, kids playing area, books...etc.
- Have a point program for the exceptional providers. Those who stay off say smoking or drugs or whatever spoils the blood. Then insures you care loyal providers who are going to continually provide you with good blood.
- Entice them with more. It's not exactly fictional that it should be clear that the powerful vampire could take a liking to a particular provider an take them as a...I dunno what to call it. But basically keep it there. That just means that your providers are actually eager to be presentable and happy. The promise of wealth or larger prizes is no joke.
- Worried about privacy or something? Put them in mask, have a camera atop the table and record the process. Should limit the claims of rape or missing body parts.
- The number of vampire in any given area should be nothing compared to humans. Even on daily feeding you have more than enough people for them to naturally regenerate the blood.
- Also vampires are not going out to eat all the time. You get a small amount of vampire who are in smaller than numbers, then from the group fewer would eat, and fewer would take the more expensive features.

**Experience**

Chances are you get vampires there on business who are only interested in coffee or drinks.
Maybe others are just there for a snack and will take the "cheap" blood bags.
Again you are not just serving 1 type of people. Provide variety to cater to all types of vampires that go to your establishment.

Maybe there is music and singing? Gambling machines? Whatever. You should not just focus on one thing.

Heck. I'm sure you gonna get vampires that might prefer blood bags or even animal blood.

In conclusion that sort of thing never stops a business. Don't even wanna talk about darker stuff like human trafficking or stuff like that.

Comment: Also, reviews for both providers and consumers to provide additional social layers and discourage negative behaviour from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the "banned drugs" illegal trade like a example...Yes you can make lots of money. Just keep it illegal.

But if you are looking after legal affordable price trade, it is like some people told before me, this will be costly impossible.

Human blood needs live humans who want give the blood or by piety or by money. How good is the relationship between humans and vamps? Is it like the relationship between healthy humans and hemophiliac humans? Healthy humans donate blood to hemophiliac humans naturally.